# UML: is this sequence diagram true for a user authentication?

Tags: authentication, uml, sequence-diagram

i'm make a sequence diagram for the registration process to a website.
The registration should include the following information:

1. First name (required)
2. Last name (required)
3. Email (required)
4. Password (required)
5. Username (optional)
6. phone number (optional)
   when submitting to register a verification email should be sent to the user's email.

This is the sequnce diagram I made:

[image]

is the sequnece correct? and do i need to make the the username and phone number messages in a alternative to indicate that they are optional or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your SD is almost correct. The fragments need to indicate the type in a tab top left which in this case would contain `alt` and also the constraint in square brackets to show the condition.

However, SDs are not meant for graphical programming. What you intend to show is better served in an activity diagram which focuses on business aspect (dialogs and their conditional order). An SD is useful to show *complex* communication between instances. Fragments should only be used sparse. The above would (in terms of implementation) better be shown in (abstract) code fragments, if ever. Any coder would prefer to look into an AD and go from there. Also think: cui bono? Who has use of it?

Comment: i'm taking the uml a course in universty . My professor , in the final project description he mentioned to inculde a SD , CD and use case of the authentication. when i asked him about it he said to make the registration and log in only. now I'm confused what should i do. I'm i doing them right ? or is there another way?

Comment: I pity you, really. UML teaching is awful in the most cases. You have to serve your prof as he wants, meanig you reproduce nonsense. You can go ahead and present both your UC and this to please him. I can't promise you a good grade since his level seems to be his own :-/

Comment: @qwert_so forgetting the fact this SD is not meant to represent the registration. the send verfication email should be a msg or a respone(dotted line) ?

Comment: I think it should be an asynch message, not  a return. Noticing that all your messages are asynch (open arrow). They probably are meant synch (filled arrow).